# Boot Fail Ubuntu HP110-210 AMD64

Tags: boot

I just obtained a second HP110 series computer. When I installed Linux 12.04.3LTS-64bit for AMD, I now get the following:

> > Checking for media......
> >
> > Media found......
> >
> > Start PXE over IPv4

The computer will still boot from the Linux disk, but I want it to boot from the HD.

I have tried several reloads of the OS and no go.

Head-desk...

Comment: Looks like you have some bad bios configuration.

Comment: That is pretty much the conclusion I came to. I spent over an hour getting my hard drive and DVD drive to show up in the storage boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues just last week when I was trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop. The problem in my case was that grub was not being installed properly.

I managed to fix it by using ubuntu boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

run ubuntu boot repair from within the live CD and choose recommended repair. And that should fix your troubles. But every system is different and they all work differently.

Further more, if you are installing only Ubuntu on this system. Then I think it would be better to install in UEFI mode (change bios from Legacy mode to UEFI or something similar) rather than MBR. As that is alot more easier.

I installed ubuntu today again in UEFI mode and I chose something else when the installer prompted to erase disk or install ubuntu next to other OS. I created the following drives.

```
efi     200mb       Efi drive
swap    16000mb     Swap disk
ext4    733000mb    root folder where ubuntu is installed "/"
```

after that everything has been working properly.

Comment: I tried to do a reinstall today by your method and every time, when I set up the efi at200mb, it would give me a 1mb free space that I couldn't do anything with and a 199mb efi. The Swap and ext4 did OK, but it would tell me that I had no place for the BIOS boot sector.

I also tried the boot repair from the terminal and got nowhere with it. It will not even boot. Also, at this point, I can not even get the system to boot to Ubuntu from a usb flash disk in the "Try but not install" mode. I'm beginning to suspect a bad BIOS or motherboard. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I got the same 199mb and 1mb free. It is totally fine. It still works. You may need to update your bios. I was having issues with wifi and I updated the bios and that resolved the issue. I would suggest that you research a bit about your computer and see if there is a bios update available and then apply that to your computer. If there is no bios update available then I would suggest to restore your bios to default settings (factory settings) and try again. On most computers it would be hitting F9 to restore default settings once you are inside the bios menu.

Comment: I have tried this numerous times to no effect.I have been on the land line with HP and they recommend that I send the computer back, under the warranty, as the BIOS is not holding its settings. I couldn't even burn the back up disks before I tried to installing Linux. I have reflashed the BIOS twice and it still isn't working right. I have had great luck with HP over the years, having several computers, printers, scanners, etc., that have exceeded 12 years of service with minimal problems but this time I got the lemon. These things happen. At least I am not putting up with a Dell...